# Adjoint of an adjoint operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If $\displaystyle \mathscr{L} =  A\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + 2B \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x \partial y} + C\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}} + D\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + E\frac{\partial }{\partial y}+F$ then prove that the adjoint of adjoint of $\mathscr{L}$ is $\mathscr{L}$. That is $\mathscr{L}^{**} = \mathscr{L}$.

I request you to help to solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I got the adjoint of L and from it I don't know how to get L**.

Comment: How did you get the adjoint of $\mathscr{L}$, and what answer did you get?

Comment: $\displaystyle \mathscr{L}^{*}(v) = \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}(Av)+2\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x \partial y}(Bv) + \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}(Cv)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(Dv)-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(Ev)+Fv$ is the adjoint of $\mathscr{L}$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the adjoint operator and properties of the hermitian inner product, you can prove that the hermitian conjugate is involutive, i.e. $(A^\dagger)^\dagger = A$ in general. Indeed, one has :
$$
\langle u, Av \rangle 
   = \langle A^\dagger u, v \rangle 
   = \langle v, A^\dagger u \rangle^* 
   = \langle (A^\dagger)^\dagger v, u \rangle^* 
   = (\langle u, (A^\dagger)^\dagger v \rangle^*)^* 
   = \langle u, (A^\dagger)^\dagger v \rangle
$$
hence the conclusion.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Abezhiko for your answer